Gain in SLLN if instead of iid we require same E
Usually, the SLLN (say, Kolmogorov's or Etemadi's) are stated for iid random variables. This said, they could also be stated by requiring just uniform and finite variance and expected value across the sequence. That is, that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\mu\qquad \mathrm{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2 \qquad\forall i\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
My question is: modellistically speaking, what do we really gain by this generalization? What are some (practical) situation where this generalization actually matters and we could not have used iid instead?
Thanks.

This generalization is not valid. Where did you find it?

My professor's notes. They are in italian, so I cannot really share them effectively. The idea is that if the above conditions and pairwise independence are given, then you don't really need anything else in the proof of it.

I think geetha290krm's point is that in your post, you say it's still true "by requiring just uniform and finite variance and expected value across the sequence" - you forgot to mention any independence assumptions, and you do need some assumption to prevent each $X_i$ being the same variable, for example.

What works is if for all $i \in{1,2,3,...}$ we have $E[X_i]=\mu$ and $Var(X_i)\leq \sigma_{max}^2$ for some finite $\mu, \sigma_{max}^2$, and if the random variables are pairwise uncorrelated (so $Cov(X_i,X_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$). This is useful because it does not require the random variables to have the same distribution. Also, pairwise uncorrelated is more general than independent.

Thank yoi for your answers, but I do understand that out of the dozens of LLNs around, conditions can get very sharp. My point was: when do we really get to use all that sharpness in an application? I was looking for examples or intuition, mainly.

@SimoneLicciardi When you collect data, you usually report summary statistics like sample mean and standard deviation. LLN tells us that under certain conditions, the summary statistics will be close to the true population values.

Yeah but that is iid. The whole point is that I don't really want them to be iid
